# Is it a good practice to use virtual inheritance as default?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Why virtual inheritance is not used as default? Default as in by the programmer and not the language.

If not, why? What are the cases where it may fail? Is there some run time overhead? Is it significant?

---

The motivation of this question comes from Stairway to heaven pattern. Its usage is not completely transparent, because of the use of virtual inheritance. If virtual inheritance was the default behaviour, it could have been used transparently. I am not saying it should be virtual by default because of this pattern.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat This question is not related to personal use, but why it is not industry standard.

Comment: In C++ the mantra normally is "don't pay for what you don't use". I.e., if you don't need virtual functions, don't use them and that means you don't have to pay for them. To answer how significant it is, you could try building two programs that differ only in this regard, and measure performance differences.

Comment: @Brandin the question is about virtual inheritance not virtual function

Comment: @q126y Same answer applies to virtual inheritance

Comment: Virtual inheritance does add overhead to your program and is only useful in the rare case that you have multiple inheritance with a diamond pattern. Why would you use something as default that adds no benefit to your code?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I was reading how stairway to heaven is not completely transparent because of the use of virtual inheritance, and wondered it wouldn't be the case, if virtual inheritance was the norm.

Comment: @q126y That point about the stairway to heaven and virtual inheritance sounds like a much better question than the one you posted. Could you edit your question to focus on that motivational example? I think at least a few of us would be able to answer it then.

Comment: @Ixrec I have edited the question. Please feel free to edit it further, if it needs any improvement.

Comment: Given that diamond inheritance is a rarity, I don't think you have to look any further for your answer.  It's not an industry-standard default because it's not commonly used.

Comment: Yes, there is overhead, in the form of complex object layouts that have to store additional pointers in virtually-inheriting objects and indirect through these to get to any virtual base class subobject. Regardless of how significant the extra size and indirection may or may not be for any given situation, there is precisely no point suffering this overhead if there is no reason for it. So, no virtual inheritance absolutely should **not** be default.